# NGINX SSI working fine, but LAST_MODIFIED returning "(none)"?

Tags: nginx, server-side-includes, last-modified

I have NGINX SSI working fine in the virtualHosts file (code below) but `LAST_MODIFIED` is returning "(none)", although the [NGINX docs for SSI](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html#ssi_last_modified) state that the `ssi_last_modified` directive appeared in version 1.5.1 (we’re running version 1.14.2).

VirtualHost file:

```
…
  location / {
    ssi on;
    ssi_last_modified on;
    …
  }
…
```

and in the .html file:

```html
<!--#if expr="$footer_id='blackfooter'" --><div id="blackfooter"><!--#else --><div id="footer"><!--#endif -->
    <!--#config timefmt="%A %d %B %Y" --><p>Updated: <!--#echo var="LAST_MODIFIED" --> | Today: <!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" --></p>
</div>
```

So for now, I've resorted to JavaScript:

```html
<!--#if expr="$footer_id='blackfooter'" --><footer id="blackfooter"><!--#else --><footer><!--#endif -->
    <!--#config timefmt="%A %d %B %Y" --><p>Updated: <span id="updated"></span> | Today: <!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" --></p>
</footer>
<script>
    let lastmod = new Date(document.lastModified);
    updated.innerHTML = lastmod.toString().substring(4,15);
</script>
```

Why is **NGINX delivering other documented SSI functionality**, but **not `LAST_MODIFIED`** in the header?

The only possible clue I found was that the `sub_filter_last_modified` is mentioned in the [docs for the NGINX ngx_http_sub_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) but AFAIK (and I'm not NGINX specialist) I'm not sure that helps much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is NGINX delivering other documented SSI functionality, but not LAST_MODIFIED in the header?

Because nginx haven't fully implement SSI anyway. Quoting [the docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html):

> Currently, the list of supported SSI commands is incomplete.

For a list of supported SSI commands and variables, check nginx's source [here](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/release-1.14.2/src/http/modules/ngx_http_ssi_filter_module.c).

---

Edit:

If complete SSI support is desired, try using Apache httpd behind nginx.

> according to the NGIX (sic) docs (see the link in my post)

Here's direct quote from [`ssi_last_modified` docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html#ssi_last_modified) circa July 21st, 2021:

> Allows preserving the `Last-Modified` header field from the original response during SSI processing to facilitate response caching.
>
> By default, the header field is removed as contents of the response are modified during processing and may contain dynamically generated elements or parts that are changed independently of the original response.

By default, when responding to a request for a static file, nginx adds `Last-Modified` HTTP response header.

When using SSI, nginx remove this header on purpose because nginx is generating the page *dynamically* instead of returning a static file, therefore adding a `Last-Modified` response header is pointless.

`ssi_last_modified` directive re-adds `Last-Modified` HTTP response header according to SSI script file timestamp.

In no way it said that this directive adds `LAST_MODIFIED` variable to nginx's SSI.

> `LAST_MODIFIED` should still be supported

AFAIK, there's no standard, nor RFCs, that could be relied upon to completely implement SSI. Arguably, [docs to mod_include](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html) could be such standard, but again, it's only a manual to another product. *Let me know if there's such standard and I'll amend this answer.*

You'll have better chance resolving this problem by submitting a feature request to [nginx's Trac](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/).

Tangent: even if it's supported, if you add `LAST_MODIFIED`, should its value be the timestamp of the SSI script, or server timestamp; since the HTML response is generated on-the-fly instead of directly read from a file.

> This is for legacy sites I've moved across to NGINX from Apache. Some large sites still use SSI, and it's a useful lightweight way approach, avoiding PHP etc.

I doubt those large sites still use SSI behind the scenes. At this point, SSI is a legacy framework with a lot of alternatives available.

Comment: Don't expect it to get added either. SSI is long-dead tech and I'm always surprised when I see someone attempting to use it. I was also a bit surprised that Igor ever added it to nginx at the beginning. It was dead even back then.

Comment: I do think SSI had its place in the past, especially since SSI is simple enough to use, and CGI didn't perform well in the first place (we're talking about pre-2000 here); though current levels of computing power and dynamics that can be delivered by *GIs (CGI, FastCGI, WSGI, etc) did put the final nail in the coffin for SSI.

Comment: Although it might not be as fully implemented as it is in Apache, according to the NGIX docs (see the link in my post) LAST_MODIFIED should still be supported, which is my question. This is for legacy sites I've moved across to NGINX from Apache. Some large sites still use SSI, and it's a useful lightweight way approach, avoiding PHP etc.

Comment: @DaveEveritt I've edited my answer and adding a few details

Comment: @DaveEveritt You have misread the docs. This option controls the Last-Modified response header, not any SSI directive. As for SSI, it had to be extremely lightweight because that's all a 486 or Pentium could handle and still manage to serve a web page in a reasonable (for the 1990s) amount of time. You must have some incredibly "legacy" sites.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. With Apache, LAST_MODIFIED gave either the date the file containing the SSI was last updated, or the date an included file was updated, which is what I'm now getting with the JavaScript, so I'll keep using JS instead.